# C# : SQL Server query issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I create a table in SQL Server Management Studio with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE contact(
ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100),
LASTNAME VARCHAR(100)
)
```

and in C# I used this code:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=BOSS; Integrated Security=TRUE");

SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter();

sd.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO contact VALUES(@ID, @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME)");

sd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
sd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
sd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;

sc.Open();

sd.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sc.Close();
```

but when I add the values to the database I get the error:

> "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized"

and I fixed it by adding `sc` to my first `insertcommand`, but when I run the program I got another error :

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'contact' can only
>   be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: You should be wrapping the connection creation in a `using` statement.

Comment: You are not connecting the DataAdapter to the connection

Comment: Why are you using a `DataAdapter` instead of a `Command` directly?

Comment: i got another problem : An explicit value for the identity column in table 'contact' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Put your new problem in a new question if you want an answer to it.

Comment: sure , thanks a lot guys , it meant a lot to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=BOSS; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
{

  using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
  {
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO contact (FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@FIRSTNAME , @LASTNAME"); 
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Connection = sc;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME", textBox2.Text); 
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", textBox3.Text); 

    sc.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

  }

}
```

Important things to note:

1) Set your table up to have the Id column as an identity column and set autoincrement to true. This will automatically generate a numeric id when you insert

2) You are trying to insert into an identity column - you can't actually do this unless you enable identity inserts. I wouldn't bother - just use an autoincrement column and let the database control the id generation step.

You can generate your table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact
 (
 Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
 FirstName varchar(100),
 LastName varchar(100)
 )
```

to get an autoincrementing primary key.

3) You don't need the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: I usually avoid the `SqlParameter.AddWithValue(..)` call - ADO.NET needs to guess the type of the data passed in, and gets it right most of the time - but it can go horribly wrong. I prefer to **explicitly** define the type so that I have no nasty surprises.....

Comment: Hi marc_s, I've never had it go wrong, but that's because I'm just usually being lazy and not defining the entire parameter, but am passing the correct type - I know that that column is an int, that column is a string and so on and so forth. It also makes it easy to write a generic run stored proc with KeyValuePair<string, object> style method. Fair comment though, especially as the user is calling the stored proc direct from fields that are driven by user input :-)

Comment: ... or if - for whatever reason - a value passed in is `null` - what datatype should ADO.NET *guess* for that???

Comment: I always parse for that and supply DBNull.Value, but, point taken :-)

Comment: That `CREATE TABLE` statement won't work on **SQL Server** .... there's no `AUTO_INCREMENT` specifier in SQL Server..

Comment: Thanks marc_s - I'm currently doing something using MySql and got my create statements mixed up. I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the connection you intend to use to the SqlCommand

```
InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO contact VALUES(@ID , @FIRSTNAME , @LASTNAME)", sc);
```

You need to dispose of your Connection and command as well. The standard pattern for doing this is:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=BOSS; Integrated Security=TRUE")){
  conn.Open();  
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn)){
     //stuff...
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: OH yeah right , i dont know how did i forgot it , thanks a lot

Comment: Care to comment on the downvote? I can't see anything wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 2):

There's no relation between `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter`.

In fact, you don't need `SqlDataAdapter`. You only need `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, for which you must use the constructor overload that accepts a connection as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ID` is an `INT IDENTITY` field, you shouldn't (and can't) insert values into it. But if you use your "generic" `INSERT` statement without explicitly specifying which columns to insert values into, your `INSERT` statement will attempt to insert data into all columns - including `ID`, which you cannot insert anything into.

The solution (which I recommend for use **always**) is to **explicitly** define which columns to insert values into:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.contact(FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME)
```

This also works if you need to change your table and add another column - your original statement will fail, since the table suddenly now would have **four columns**, but your statement would only provide three values. If you explicitly define which columns you want to provide values for, your statement is more robust and works better.

So your complete code should look like this:

```
using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=BOSS; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
using(SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Contact(FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME)", sc))
{
   cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@FIRSTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox2.Text;
   cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@LASTNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox3.Text;

   sc.Open();
   cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sc.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `sd.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO contact VALUES(@ID , @FIRSTNAME , @LASTNAME)", sc);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do either ways:

a. Set you connection object to the adapter's insertcommand connection:

```
sd.InsertCommand.Connection = sc;
```

Or

b. Pass your connection object while initializing insert command as below:

```
sd.InsertCommand = 
 new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO contact VALUES(@ID, @FIRSTNAME, @LASTNAME)", sc);
```