# ASP.NET C# - Insert into compound keys

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to perform an update and insert command on 'edit account' page where users can edit their information. When a user logs in, they will be redirected to a 'My Account' page which will display all their information.

My edit account page looks like this:

[Edit account page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn03z.png)

The edit account page will be accessing/inserting data into 3 tables:

1. Member

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member]
    (
       [MemberID]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
       [MemberName] VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
       [Phone]      BIGINT       NOT NULL,
       [Email]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
       [Username]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
       [Password]   NCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberID] ASC)
   );
2. Address

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address]
    (
       [AddressID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
       [HouseNumber]  VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
       [AddressLine1] VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
       [AddressLine2] NCHAR (30)     NOT NULL,
       [City]         NCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
       [PostCode]     NCHAR (7)      NOT NULL,
       [AddressType]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressID] ASC)
   );
3. Address_Member

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address_Member]
    (
       [MemberID]  INT NOT NULL,
       [AddressID] INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MemberID] ASC, [AddressID] ASC),
       CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Member_Address] FOREIGN KEY ([AddressID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Address] ([AddressID]),
       CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Member_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([MemberID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([MemberID])
   );

The following is the code in editaccount.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class EditAccount : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlCommand com;
            string str;

            conn.Open();
            str = "SELECT Address.HouseNumber, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.PostCode, Address.AddressType, Address_Member.MemberID, Address_Member.AddressID, Member.MemberName, Member.Phone, Member.Email, Member.Username FROM Address INNER JOIN Address_Member ON Address.AddressID = Address_Member.AddressID RIGHT JOIN Member ON Address_Member.MemberID = Member.MemberID WHERE Member.Email = '" + Session["Email"] + "'";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {

                TxtEName.Text = reader["MemberName"].ToString();
                LblEUser.Text = reader["Username"].ToString();
                TxtEEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                TxtEPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
                TxtEType.Text = reader["AddressType"].ToString();
                TxtEHouse.Text = reader["HouseNumber"].ToString();
                TxtEA1.Text = reader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
                TxtEA2.Text = reader["AddressLine2"].ToString();
                TxtECity.Text = reader["City"].ToString();
                TxtEPostcode.Text = reader["PostCode"].ToString();

                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dadt = new DataTable();
        DataTable da = new DataTable();



        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Address.HouseNumber, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.PostCode, Address.AddressType, Address_Member.MemberID, Address_Member.AddressID, Member.MemberName, Member.Phone, Member.Email, Member.Username FROM Address INNER JOIN Address_Member ON Address.AddressID = Address_Member.AddressID INNER JOIN Member ON Address_Member.MemberID = Member.MemberID WHERE Member.Email = '" + Session["Email"] + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            adapter.Fill(dadt);
            adapter.Fill(da);



            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string membercmd = "UPDATE Member SET MemberName=@MemberName,Email=@Email,Phone=@Phone";
                SqlCommand Member = new SqlCommand(membercmd, conn);

                Member.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberName", TxtEName.Text);
                Member.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TxtEEmail.Text);
                Member.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", TxtEPhone.Text);
                Member.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            if (da.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string Addresscmd = "UPDATE Address SET HouseNumber ='" + TxtEHouse.Text + "', AddressLine1 = '" + TxtEA1.Text + "', AddressLine2 = '" + TxtEA2.Text + "', City = '" + TxtECity.Text + "',PostCode = '" + TxtEPostcode.Text + "', AddressType = '" + TxtEType.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand Address = new SqlCommand(Addresscmd, conn);
                Address.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            else
            {

                string AddressInsert = "INSERT INTO Address (HouseNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, AddressType) VALUES (@HouseNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @Postcode, @AddressType)";
                SqlCommand Address1 = new SqlCommand(AddressInsert, conn);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNumber", TxtEHouse.Text);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", TxtEA1.Text);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", TxtEA2.Text);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TxtECity.Text);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", TxtEPostcode.Text);
                Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressType", TxtEType.Text);
                Address1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string AddressMember = "INSERT INTO Address_Member (AddressID,MemberID) VALUES (@AddressID,@MemberID)";
                SqlCommand Address_Member = new SqlCommand(AddressMember, conn);
                Address_Member.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


                conn.Close();
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Changes saved')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("~/MyAccount.aspx");


        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Changes not saved')</script>" + ex);
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

When I perform an insert command, new data was inserted but I do not know how to insert the IDs into the Address_Member table where the information are linked with each other and eventually display on my account page.

I also got this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@AddressID"

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL when you're using SQL Server?

Comment: See this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370840/c-sharp-sql-server-query-issue

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because @AddressID is not specified as a parameter for Address_Member.

If you add a parameter called @AddressID to Address_Member and give it a valid value that should fix the error.

Comment: I am aware of that. But AddressID and MemberID in Address_Member table are foreign keys. I do not know how to get the addressID and memberID from Address and Member table to be inserted into the Address_Member table. If I add a parameter called @AddressID I do not know what to write for the value as MemberID and AddressID are auto incremented.

Comment: If you are updating Address row @AddressID would be obtained in your reader in Page_Load.
If you inserting a new Address row then you'll have to add an output parameter to Address_Member which returns the auto incremented ID value.  The T-SQL SCOPE_IDENTITY() will return the newly inserted ID.  I'm not sure if that can only be used within a SQL Stored Procedure or if it can also be applied to a an INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
string AddressInsert = "INSERT INTO Address (HouseNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, AddressType) VALUES (@HouseNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @Postcode, @AddressType)";
SqlCommand Address1 = new SqlCommand(AddressInsert, conn);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNumber", TxtEHouse.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", TxtEA1.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", TxtEA2.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TxtECity.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", TxtEPostcode.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressType", TxtEType.Text);
Address1.ExecuteNonQuery();

string AddressMember = "INSERT INTO Address_Member (AddressID,MemberID) VALUES (@AddressID,@MemberID)";
SqlCommand Address_Member = new SqlCommand(AddressMember, conn);
Address_Member.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

change to

```
string AddressInsert = @"
    INSERT INTO Address (HouseNumber, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, Postcode, AddressType) 
    VALUES (@HouseNumber, @AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @City, @Postcode, @AddressType);

    declare @AddressID numeric(38,0)= (select SCOPE_IDENTITY()); -- if your column type is different , deal SCOPE_IDENTITY type should be same with your column

    INSERT INTO Address_Member (AddressID,MemberID) VALUES (
    @AddressID,@MemberID )
";
SqlCommand Address1 = new SqlCommand(AddressInsert, conn);
//new (get MemberID)
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", dt.Select().SingleOrDefault()["MemberID"]);
//old
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HouseNumber", TxtEHouse.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", TxtEA1.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", TxtEA2.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TxtECity.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", TxtEPostcode.Text);
Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressType", TxtEType.Text);
Address1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

hope help you :)

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your answer. but i've got an error on this line: Address1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberID", dt.Select().SingleOrDefault()["MemberID"]);-  It says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: it mean your select from member sql query nothing
this one,it should have a value
"SELECT Address.HouseNumber, Address.AddressLine1, Address.AddressLine2, Address.City, Address.PostCode, Address.AddressType, Address_Member.MemberID, Address_Member.AddressID, Member.MemberName, Member.Phone, Member.Email, Member.Username FROM Address INNER JOIN Address_Member ON Address.AddressID = Address_Member.AddressID INNER JOIN Member ON Address_Member.MemberID = Member.MemberID WHERE Member.Email = '" + Session["Email"] + "'";

Comment: Ok, I have edited the code but it's still giving me the same error when I debug it.

Comment: please show top 5 data when you query the sql without personal information